# ld: file not found: i386

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, ld, 32-bit

I'm trying to link a 32Bit simple object file with ld, but I only get this error message

```
ld: warning: option -m is obsolete and being ignored
ld: file not found: i386
```

On first sight I thought it was just a simple syntax error, because i386 is not a file, it should be the architecture. My command line looks like this:

```
ld add64.o -m i386 -static -o JulianTest
```

According to the man pages this syntax should be correct.

Maybe I should also mention that I used :

```
nasm -g -f elf32 myfile.asm
```

to compile and that I'm on a 64Bit-System (OS X), furthermore this is my add64.asm:

```
section .data

section .bss

section .text
    global _start

    mov eax, 0x11111111
    mov ebx, 0x22222222
    mov ecx, 0x33333333
    mov edx, 0x44444444

    add ebx, edx
    adc eax, ecx
    int 80h
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe the mac `ld` no longer supports 32 bit code? If you have `gcc` try `gcc -v -m32 test.c` with some simple test code to see how that invokes the linker. PS: your code is broken too

Comment: I'm thinking that you really don't intend to create _ELF_ binaries and you are creating OS/X binaries. In that case, the problem is with _NASM_. If targeting 64-bit try building with macho-64 format using `nasm -g -f macho64 myfile.asm`. If targeting 32-bit macho format you'd use `nasm -g -f macho32 myfile.asm`

Comment: As for why _LD_ is complaining, the OS/X version of _LD_ doesn't use the same options and parameters as its Linux counterpart.

Comment: Your `int 0x80` call will fail as the parameters  aren't being set up properly and I think you'll want to change `_start` to `start` (withut the underscore) and you'll also want to put a `start:` label before `mov eax, 0x11111111` .